# copy_backward or copy with reverse_iterators?

Tags: c++, stl

In terms of practical usage what differences are there between

a) copy_backward

b) copy with reverse_iterators for source and destination

In particular is one more generally applicable than the other? Are there any other differences?

Update: If there's really no difference, then any reference in C++ literature to this equivalence is appreciated. The motivation behind this question is to understand if this was by design or one of those slip ups (like missing copy_if)

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if, in practice, using a `reverse_iterator` requires the iterator type to be properly tagged whereas `copy_backward` is implemented as a simple loop. Obviously that's not guaranteed, though. As far as the standard is concerned, all iterators must be tagged.

Comment: hmm... along the same lines could reverse_iterator perhaps be slower in case the original iterator is a T*?

Comment: `T*` is tagged as a random-access iterator, since there is a guaranteed partial specialization `template<class T> struct iterator_traits<T*>;`.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, use of copy_backward() clearly shows developer's intention to copy interval in reverse order.

copy_backward() works with original bidirectional iterators, while the reverse_iterator is an adaptor of a bidirectional iterator and may be not as effective as original iterator.

Using the reverse_iterator makes sense when you need to apply an algorithm for input iterators like copy() to reverse sequence, but don't have counterpart for bidirectional operators like copy_backward().

Therefore, there are conceptual *and* practical differences.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/ has a implementation of `std::copy`

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy_backward/ has a implementation of `std::copy_backward`

You can see the differences by yourself.

**Note:** If I were you I would use `std::copy_backward`, because calling `std::copy` with the `std::reverse_iterator<T>` class might be a little slower (it needs more memory than a bidirectional iterator)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `copy` returns an iterator to the pass-the-end element while `copy_backward` returns an iterator to the first element.

They are not equivalent in that sense.

- The signatures of course differ. `copy` is ok with `InputIterator`s and `OutputIterator`. Whilst `copy_backward` expects `BidirectionalIterator`s.
- The effect on the container (when used correctly) is the same, but the returned iterators are of different types and point to different elements.

Example:

This works because `vector` can use `RandomAccessIterator` which does support the properties expected by `InputIterator`, `OutputIterator` and `BidirectionalIterator`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void printer(int i) {
    cout << i << ", ";
}

int main() {

    int mynumbers[] = {3, 9, 0, 2, 1, 4, 5};
    vector<int> v1(mynumbers, mynumbers + 7);

    vector<int>::iterator it = copy_backward(mynumbers, mynumbers + 7, v1.end());
    for_each(v1.begin(), v1.end(), printer);
    cout << endl << "Returned element: " << *it;
    cout << endl;

    vector<int>::reverse_iterator rit = copy(mynumbers, mynumbers + 7, v1.rbegin());
    for_each(v1.begin(), v1.end(), printer);
    cout << endl << "Before the first element (reverse end)? " << (rit == v1.rend());
    rit--; // go to first element, because it is a reverse iterator
    cout << endl << "Returned element: " << *rit;

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
3, 9, 0, 2, 1, 4, 5, 
Returned element: 3
5, 4, 1, 2, 0, 9, 3, 
Before the first element (reverse end)? 1
Returned element: 5
```

If you'd use a container that does not support `BidirectionalIterator` then you risk trouble (e.g. if you'd try to copy backward a `forward_list` because it uses a `ForwardIterator`, which is does not support operations provided by a `BidirectionalIterator`).
Also in this case copying with reverse iterator on `forward_list` is also not possible, because it does not support reverse iterators.

Basically, you need to make sure the container's iterators are supported and choose according to which end of the container you'd like to have returned. Otherwise the effect is the same.

Answer (score -1):

There no differences practically.
In the same manner you can compare forward copying.

a) copy

b) copy_backward with reverse iterators.

Comment: That's technically not true since copy is more general in that it can be used with input/output iterators. It doesn't require bidirectional iterators.

Comment: So you answered your question =)
There is a technical difference.

Comment: @inkooboo: that's a difference between your (a) and (b): one requires at least a bidirectional iterator, and the other doesn't. The same difference doesn't apply to hawk's (a) and (b), since they both require at least a bidirectional iterator.

Answer (score -1):

There shouldn't be any difference, however:
copy_backward comes handy in case the iterator is result of some function call and also much cleaner than using copy with reverse iterators.